# Want the numbers in between two limits with equal time interval

Tags: arduino

I try to get values in between 10 and 100 so I arrange

```
int pos;
long previousTime =0;
int increment = 1;
int interval = 10;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  long currentTime = millis();
  if(currentTime - previousTime > interval){
    previousTime = currentTime;
    pos +=increment;
    if(pos<= 10 || pos > 100){
      increment = -increment;
    }
    Serial.println(pos);
  }


}
```

But my output showing  only 1 and 0.If I reduce lower limit into 0 or 1 then I got values in between those limit values given inside the if statement but not getting proper result when I increase the lower limit.Why?
[image: output look like this :]

Comment: Please 1) fix the error `expected primary-expression before ';' token` 2) check your curly braces 3) add variable definitions

Comment: Actually I did that and compile successfully but here typed wrong! @datafiddler

Comment: Right, so we can't help you fix your code if we can't see your actual code.  Please copy and past the WHOLE THING so that we can see the entire program.  The error may not be in the part you think it is.

Comment: You will always remain below the lower boundary

Comment: @datafiddler but pos incremented by 1 and I posted whole thing

Comment: @datafiddler oho yeha you are right man If I increase the initial value it works fine.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok your problem is simple now that we can see the whole code.  Look at position, it starts out at 0.  On the first pass through loop it gets increments to 1.  Then that if statement checks and 1 is indeed less than 10 so it makes increment -1.  Then on the next pass through loop that gets added making pos 0 again and since 0 is less than 10 it reverses increment again.  It’s doing exactly what you told it.

Try starting pos out at the 10 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not trivial to you, here a suggestion

```
int pos=0;
unsigned long previousTime =0;
int increment = 1;
int interval = 10;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  if(currentTime - previousTime >= interval){
    previousTime = currentTime;

    pos += increment;

    if(pos <=  10) increment = 1;
    if(pos >= 100) increment = -1; 
    // else leave increment as is ...

    Serial.println(pos);
  }
}
```